# Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (ID)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I'm getting the conversion error when I try to import a text file to my database. Below is the error message I received:

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (ID).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (ID).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 1 (ID).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 4, column 1 (ID).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 5, column 2 (date).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 6, column 1 (ID).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 7, column 1 (ID).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 8, column 1 (ID).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 9, column 1 (ID).

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 10, column 1 (ID).

**Here is my table query code:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testpostingvoucher](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [checkdigit] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [credit] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Here is my bulk insert query code:**

```
bulk insert [dbo].[testpostingvoucher]
from 'D:\HBL Scrolls\testbulk.txt'
with
    (
        fieldterminator = '|',
        rowterminator = '.00|'
    )
go
```

**Here is the sample data from text file:**

```
YOUR ACCOUNT STATEMENT                                             ACCOUNT NO    : 0042-79000275-03 OF
   FOR THE PERIOD ENDING: FEB01,2020 TO JUN30,2020                                    STATE LIFE, KARACHI BRANCH
   CDGK-MAIN COLLECTION A/C                                           ACCOUNT TYPE  : NON-CHEQUEING A/C.
   CMD HBL STATE LIFE CORPORATE CENTRE                                CURRENCY      : Pakistan Rupee
   STATE LIFE BUILDING NO-9                                           PRINTING DATE :  3-11-20
   ZIA UDDIN AHMED ROAD                                               FREQUENCY     : INTERIM / DUPLICATE
   KARACHI                                                            PAGE NO       :    1

                                                              

    USER          : HJ6201
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |DATE   |VALUE  |PARTICULARS                        |             DEBIT|            CREDIT|             BALANCE |
   
|-------|-------|-----------------------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
   |       |       |BROUGHT FORWARD                    |                  |                  |                 .00 |
   |01FEB20|       |CMD CREDIT        0067031010700068 |                  |          2,042.00|            2,042.00 |
   |       |       |14C.D.G.KC012386O00001             |                  |                  |                     |
   |       |       |2386                               |                  |                  |                     |
```

Comment: Is `value` equal to your `ID`? If not, what is your `ID` in the sample text?

Comment: The sample data doesn't seem to match the table at all.

Comment: There is simply no way to import your text file into a table in the manner you attempted. Without knowing your goal and what you expect the contents of your table to be after importing the file snippet you posted, it is impossible to provide useful suggestions.

Comment: @SMor I want  to insert specific data of file into table for example:
Date : 01FEB20
checkdigit: CMD CREDIT        0067031010700068
credit: 2,042.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like some value is trying to get inserted into a column that does not accept that value. So in your ID column, which requires and INT, you potentially have another character in the value. You can try to make every column a `NVARCHAR(max)`, load all the data, then query and see what is in the column that isn't an INT using `isnumberic()`.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testpostingvoucher](
[ID] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[date] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[checkdigit] varchar NULL,
[credit] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL -- probably want to use DECIMAL(18,2) instead of INT
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: your solutions is suitable for inserting data into table but i want to insert only specific columns in a table. for example 
Date : 01FEB20
checkdigit: CMD CREDIT        0067031010700068
credit: 2,042.00

Answer (score 0):

That row terminator looks weird to me.

```
BULK INSERT testpostingvoucher
FROM 'E:\\file.txt' --location with filename
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

What row does your data actually start on?  There is an optional argument to choose the FIRSTROW.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE testpostingvoucher

BULK INSERT testpostingvoucher
FROM 'E:\ETLFiles\tsp1.txt'
WITH (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
     FIRSTROW=15
)

SELECT *
FROM testpostingvoucher
```

See the links below for more ideas.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5345/nonstandard-delimiters-for-columns-and-rows-using-sql-server-bulk-insert/

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6041/sql-server-staging-table-vs-temp-table/

You could set all the data types in the table that you are inserting to (staging table), to varchar(max), load your data, and then copy everything to a final, strongly-typed table (production table).